# Json decode api in php foreach failing

Tags: php, json, foreach

Almost have this working but am just missing some stupid thing.

Most of this has been taken from the Cryptsy API example.

The variables are getting filled but just have something wrong with the foreach syntax.

The error I am getting is "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() " on the foreach($marketinfo as $marketdata){ line

```
$result = json_decode($res,true);

foreach($result as $marketinfo){
    foreach($marketinfo as $marketdata){
        $marketid = $marketdata['marketid'];
        $label = $marketdata['label'];
        $pcc = $marketdata['primary_currency_code'];
        $pc = $marketdata['primary_currency_name'];
        $scc = $marketdata['secondary_currency_code'];
        $sc = $marketdata['secondary_currency_name'];
        $cv = $marketdata['current_volume'];
    }
}
```

A little help to get through this would be appreciated.

Comment: I think it would be a good idea to show at least part of the content of the JSON string in `$res` in order to illustrate what you want to achieve.

Comment: What's the need for the second foreach loop? just use the first one since it does the exact same thing

Comment: Make sure `$marketinfo` is an array and not a string. You may only need to do one `foreach()` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find out what type $marketinfo is.  Use [is_array()](https://www.php.net/is_array) and/or [gettype()](https://www.php.net/gettype), example:

```
$result = json_decode($res,true);

try {
foreach($result as $key=>$marketinfo){
    if(is_array($marketinfo)){
       foreach($marketinfo as $marketdata){
           $marketid = $marketdata['marketid'];
           $label = $marketdata['label'];
           $pcc = $marketdata['primary_currency_code'];
           $pc = $marketdata['primary_currency_name'];
           $scc = $marketdata['secondary_currency_code'];
           $sc = $marketdata['secondary_currency_name'];
           $cv = $marketdata['current_volume'];
       }
    }else{
       throw new Exception($key . ' $marketinfo is not an array, is '.gettype($marketinfo));
    }
}
}catch(Exception $e){
   echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: OK, so it looks like everyone is right, the $marketinfo is a string. I assumed I needed the second foreach to deal with the nested array output by the json_decode.

Comment: OK, so it looks like everyone is right, the $marketinfo is a string. I assumed I needed the second foreach to deal with the nested array output by the json_decode.

The $res before the json_decode looks like string '{"success":"1","return":[{"marketid":"141","label":"42\/BTC","primary_currency_code":"42","primary_currency_name":"42Coin","secondary_currency_code":"BTC","secondary_currency_name":

Answer (score 0):

The most likely problem is that `$marketinfo` is not an array.

`echo` or `print_r()` `$marketinfo` to confirm that its content is an array before looping it with the foreach.

Comment: It appears the marketinfo is fine, print_r output is 

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [marketid] => 141
            [label] => 42/BTC
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [marketid] => 199
            [label] => AC/BTC

Comment: @RobH71 did you `print_r()` `$marketinfo` inside the outer `foreach` loop?